# How to get next year date from the user entered date in java

Tags: java-7

Below is the code that returning wrong date

```
String dt = "01-08-2021";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(dt);
       
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
      
date = cal.getTime();
System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

It printing as 31-08-2021, it suppose to print 31-07-2022.
If I pass 02-08-2021, it working perfectly 01-08-2022
I am using java1.7. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether thats the issue... but: you're using the SimpleDateFormat wrong. `MM` stands for month. `mm` stands for Minute. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Exactly. Attaching a debugger, I see that month=1. So the parsed date is 08:00 on 1 Jan 2021, thus subtracting a day gives 31 Dec 2020 08:00, and adding a year gives 31 Dec 2021 08:00, which is then displayed as 31-08-2021.

Comment: after changing from mm to MM, it worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You do not need line - cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1) in your code.

You can try below code, it working fine

```
        String dt = "01-08-2021";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy").parse(dt);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

        date = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println(format.format(date));
```

Comment: Thanks, but removing the DATE line hides the issue - which is that 8 isn't a month, it's an hour.

Comment: @shivakumar sajjan, i need that line. reason i need to calculate current date and expiry date.